# Redirect all urls starting with /5

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a couple of old urls that were put there by hackers, and I'm trying to remove all these links in Google. How can I redirect all URLS to the homepage starting with /5

I have multiple urls:

```
domain.com/5688/...
domain.com/5736/...
domain.com/5211/...
domain.com/5262/...
```

Every URL that needs to be redirected starts with /5, but how can I redirect all these urls? I have the following string in my htaccess file but its not working:

```
RewriteRule ^5(/|$) / [R]
```

Comment: Redirect to where?

Comment: @motanelu in his question he specifies his homepage... "_How can I redirect all URLS to the homepage starting with /5_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RedirectMatch ^/5 http://example.com/
```

This will redirect all uris starting with **/5** to http://example.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can use [mod_alias `RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) for redirections.

```
RedirectMatch permanent "^/5" "/"
```

Comment: Thank you, you redirected me instantly to home